# Android studio Application Not Install error [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]

Tags: android, gradle

i am getting Failure "`[INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]`" when ever i run the application.

i check the various solutions in stack but the solution was not help full

also i am getting another error in same project

```
"Unexpected Error
 Local path doesn't exist.
 Local path doesn't exist.

The project may need to be synced with Gradle files.

**Sync Project with Gradle files**
```

help me please